# Create PDF Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I want to create a pdf page from html file in Laravel but I do not know how to do it. You can help me
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: Please follow this link https://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-laravel-54

Comment: I personally recommended you to use another package of barryvdh ***laravel-snappy***. See the link [laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Import in top of controller file
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;


// use below code to generate and download pdf file
$pdf = PDF::loadView('bladefilename', ['arrayname' => $array]);
return $pdf->download('filename.pdf');
```

Write Above code in the controller file

In Blade file (HTML file) set array data.

Show Below Link : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/126

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little bit late but hopefully this will help someone.

There are 2 ways:

- Create HTML page and use jspdf to print this page. The best way is to use html2pdf: https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js 
  You can use this one to convert html to canvas and print to pdf. All css will be kept but you have to change the page to fix the space between pages as there may be some bad cut at the end of each page.
- Print the page using latex. You have to use laravel latex compiler: https://github.com/fvhockney/latexcompiler
  It is a little bit harder to styling the page but there is no problem with paging.